# NullPointerException variables

Tags: java, android, oop, nullpointerexception

I declared two member variables in the `MainActivity` and I initialize them as soon as I get the location inside a method.

The problem is that if I call them from another `activity` using a static method or creating an object I have a `NullPointerException`.

How to solve this?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public static final String DAILY_FORECAST = "DAILY_FORECAST";
public static final String HOURLY_FORECAST = "HOURLY_FORECAST";

private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private Forecast mForecast;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Location mLastLocation;
private double mLatitude;
private double mLongitude;
public static String mCity; // declared here
private static String mAdminArea; // declared here

@Bind(R.id.locationLabel) TextView mLocationLabel;
@Bind(R.id.timeLabel) TextView mTimeLabel;
@Bind(R.id.temperatureLabel) TextView mTemperatureLabel;
@Bind(R.id.humidityValue) TextView mHumidityValue;
@Bind(R.id.precipValue) TextView mPrecipValue;
@Bind(R.id.summaryLabel) TextView mSummaryLabel;
@Bind(R.id.iconImageView) ImageView mIconImageView;
@Bind(R.id.refreshImageView) ImageView mRefreshImageView;
@Bind(R.id.progressBar) ProgressBar mProgressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    toggleRefresh();

    buildGoogleApiClient();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    mRefreshImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getForecast(mLatitude, mLongitude);
        }
    });
}

@Override
 protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
}

private void getForecast(double latitude, double longitude) {
    String apiKey = "48fb6c0ca3567d0b17bf99b400ef5606";
    String forecastUrl = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/" + apiKey +
            "/" + latitude + "," + longitude;
    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        toggleRefresh();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(forecastUrl)
                .build();

        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        toggleRefresh();
                    }
                });
                alertUserAboutError();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        toggleRefresh();
                    }
                });

                try {
                    String jsonData = response.body().string();
                    Log.v(TAG, jsonData);
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        mForecast = parseForecastDetails(jsonData);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                updateDisplay();
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        alertUserAboutError();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught: ", e);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught: ", e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.network_unavailable_message),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private void toggleRefresh() {
    if (mProgressBar.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mRefreshImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mRefreshImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

private void updateDisplay() {
    Current current = mForecast.getCurrent();

    mTemperatureLabel.setText(current.getTemperature() + "");
    mTimeLabel.setText("At " + current.getFormattedTime() + " it will be");
    mHumidityValue.setText(current.getHumidity() + "");
    mPrecipValue.setText(current.getPrecipChance() + "%");
    mSummaryLabel.setText(current.getSummary());

    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(current.getIconId());
    mIconImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}

private Forecast parseForecastDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
    Forecast forecast = new Forecast();

    forecast.setCurrent(getCurrentDetails(jsonData));
    forecast.setHourlyForecast(getHourlyForecast(jsonData));
    forecast.setDailyForecast(getDailyForecast(jsonData));

    return forecast;
}

private Day[] getDailyForecast(String jsonData) throws JSONException {JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
    String timezone = forecast.getString("timezone");
    JSONObject daily = forecast.getJSONObject("daily");
    JSONArray data = daily.getJSONArray("data");

    Day[] days = new Day[data.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonDay = data.getJSONObject(i);
        Day day = new Day();

        day.setSummary(jsonDay.getString("summary"));
        day.setIcon(jsonDay.getString("icon"));
        day.setTime(jsonDay.getLong("time"));
        day.setTemperatureMax(jsonDay.getDouble("temperatureMax"));
        day.setTimezone(timezone);

        days[i] = day;
    }

    return days;
}

private Hour[] getHourlyForecast(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
    String timezone = forecast.getString("timezone");
    JSONObject hourly = forecast.getJSONObject("hourly");
    JSONArray data = hourly.getJSONArray("data");

    Hour[] hours = new Hour[data.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonHour = data.getJSONObject(i);
        Hour hour = new Hour();

        hour.setSummary(jsonHour.getString("summary"));
        hour.setTemperature(jsonHour.getDouble("temperature"));
        hour.setIcon(jsonHour.getString("icon"));
        hour.setTime(jsonHour.getLong("time"));
        hour.setTimezone(timezone);

        hours[i] = hour;
    }

    return hours;
}

private Current getCurrentDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
    String timezone = forecast.getString("timezone");

    Log.i(TAG, "From JSON: " + timezone);

    JSONObject currently = forecast.getJSONObject("currently");

    Current current = new Current();
    current.setHumidity(currently.getDouble("humidity"));
    current.setTime(currently.getInt("time"));
    current.setSummary(currently.getString("summary"));
    current.setTemperature(currently.getInt("temperature"));
    current.setIcon(currently.getString("icon"));
    current.setPrecipChance(currently.getDouble("precipProbability"));
    current.setTimeZone(timezone);

    Log.d(TAG, current.getFormattedTime());

    return current;
}

private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isAvailable = false;
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        isAvailable = true;
    }
    return isAvailable;
}

private void alertUserAboutError() {
    AlertDialogFragment dialog = new AlertDialogFragment();
    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "error_dialog");
}

@OnClick (R.id.dailyButton)
public void startDailyActivity(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DailyForecastActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(DAILY_FORECAST, mForecast.getDailyForecast());
    startActivity(intent);
}

@OnClick(R.id.hourlyButton)
public void startHourlyActivity(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HourlyForecastActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(HOURLY_FORECAST, mForecast.getHourlyForecast());
    startActivity(intent);
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Toast.makeText(this,getString(R.string.connection_suspended),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Toast.makeText(this,getString(R.string.connection_failed),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    toggleRefresh();

    mLatitude = 37.8267;
    mLongitude = -122.423;

    getForecast(mLatitude, mLongitude);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;

    mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    mLongitude = location.getLongitude();

    getLocationName(mLatitude, mLongitude);

    toggleRefresh();
    getForecast(mLatitude, mLongitude);

    //remove location updates if you just need one location:
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
}

private void getLocationName(Double latitude, Double longitude) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,
                longitude, 1);

        if (addresses != null) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            mCity = address.getLocality(); // initialised here
            mAdminArea = address.getAdminArea(); // initialised here


            if (mAdminArea != null) {
                mLocationLabel.setText(mCity.toString() + ", " + mAdminArea);
            }
            else {
                mLocationLabel.setText(mCity.toString());
            }
        }
        else {
            mLocationLabel.setText("No Locality Founded!");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        mLocationLabel.setText("Cannot get Locality!");
    }
}

public static String getCity() {
    return mCity;
}

public static String getAdminArea() {
    return mAdminArea;
}
}
```

Comment: please show us some code

Comment: How would we come to know what are those variables about and what you are doing actually? Share some code

Comment: they all are right , please show some code before getting the question downrating as it is not so clear.

Comment: You also need to show the stack trace

Comment: It disappeared. I post it again.

Comment: Just define them in application class of your code and access them throughout application life cycle and you can change them from location listener service and before use these variable check that they are null or not.

Answer (score 1):

"The problem is that if I call them from another activity using a static method or creating an object I have a NullPointerException. "

This is very very bad decision.
If you need this variables in activity that starts from MainActivity, then use `intent.putExtra`. In other cases better solution will be using of Application class

Comment: I don't start that activity from the main.

Comment: Than use Application class to save your variables or create some singletone to store it. Better way will be store it in shared preferencess

Answer (score 1):

Static variables are associated with a class and they will live as long as the class is in the memory.

So, if you will access from other activity and that class is not in the memory you will get `null` value. To avoid this i will recommend you to pass value from one activity to another using `Bundle` or `Intent`.

or You can set value in `SharedPreferences` or create getter and setter in your `Application class` and access it in any activity.

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.app.Application;


public class YourApplication extends Application {

    private static YourApplication mInstance;
    String city,adminArea;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static YourApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getAdminArea() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setAdminArea(String adminArea) {
        this.country = country;
    }
}
```

and in your activity call them like:

```
YourApplication.getInstance().getCity();
YourApplication.getInstance().setCity("You city");
```

In your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:name=".YourApplication" .....put this line in your manifest file>
```

Comment: There is still a problem. When I extend Application, there is an error that says: "Interface expected here"

Comment: just create new java class as i have written in code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84159/discussion-between-lalit-pratap-singh-and-agostinelli).